# Issue to align the text within a scrolling banner to the right

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to get the text of a rotating banner (the text in red) aligned to the right (to the left of the social icons). It would be too long to post the code here so [here is a link](http://goo.gl/2G5TGT) where you can see it in action (note that I'm using modern-ticker plugin).

I suspect that this could come from the below code (part of modern-ticker.css) but when I change it to `float: right` the text disappears. I also tried text-align: right at various places without success. Thanks for your help!

```
.mt-news li {
        float: left;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating elements get as wide as their content, so you need to specify it in order to be as wide as the container (in this case the container is very very wide but the visible area is 400px wide).

```
.mt-news li {
    width: 400px;
}
```

---

More changes

In this example, you don't really need the parent to be very wide and the `li`s to float because you're fading them in a way that they're not displayed at once. I would recommend:

1. Remove `width: 50000px;` from `ul`
2. Remove `float: left;` from `li`
3. Remove `float: left;` from `.mt-news`

That is if the real live situation won't be different from this example.